# Convert upstart script to systemd for django channel on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, systemd, upstart, django-channels

I am following http://masnun.rocks/2016/11/02/deploying-django-channels-using-daphne this tutorial to deploy Django channel on Nginx.In this tutorial, they used upstart script to run daphne serve.I need to convert upstart script to systemd because i am working on ubuntu 16.04.

Below is upstart script

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

script
    cd /home/ubuntu/Project/projectname
    export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="projectname.settings"
    exec daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 projectname.asgi:channel_layer
end script
```

Below is systemd script which i converted

```
[Unit]
Description=daphne server script 

[Service]
Environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="projectname.settings"
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/Project/projectname
ExecStart=daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 projectname.asgi:channel_layer
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When i run systemd service status it gave me below error

Failed to get properties: No such interface ''

Comment: What is the contents of your `settings.py`? Might you have an old IP laying around from a different machine?

Comment: @Matt Clark Is my systemd file correct?

Comment: @ArtiBerde did this line: Environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="projectname.settings", work for you?

Comment: @jhc No, I changed my setting to [Unit]
Description=daphne

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/Projectname
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 Projectname.asgi:channel_layer
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: [Unit]
Description=runworker

[Service]

WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/Projectname
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 manage.py runworker
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target and my django channel is up and running properly on nginx

Comment: @ArtiBerde So the django_settings_module line isn't actually required? Did you get websockets working?

Comment: @jhcYes.with the two script mention in the comment and I gave daphne URL in my nginx file

Comment: @ArtiBerde do you mind helping me? On my AWS instance, daphne and the worker are both running fine (I can do http requests and even internal from same domain websocket connections), but as soon as I try to websockets from an external domain javascript client, it does not work.

See -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655488/running-django-channels-with-daphne-on-systemd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man systemd.service` in the section on  `ExecStart=`:

> For each of the specified commands, the first argument must be an absolute path to an executable.

You have other problems, but first you need to provide a full path to `daphne`. You can check your file with:

```
systemd-analyze verify /path/to/your/file.service
```