# Running Daphne with DotEnv in a systemd service

Tags: django, systemd, daphne

I'm using a `.env` file which contains the configuration for my Django app. I have a `systemd` service which runs Daphne (similar to what's below)

```
[Unit]
Description=WebSocket Daphne Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/django/myproject/src
ExecStart=/home/django/myproject/venv/bin/python /home/django/myproject/venv/bin/daphne -e ssl:8001:privateKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/myproject.com/privkey.pem:certKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/myproject.com/fullchain.pem myproject.asgi:application  
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Moreover, I'm using `gunicorn` through a similar mechanism, which works perfect. However, `Daphne` does not.

When I run it through `systemctl start daphne.service`, it tells me that Django settings are improperly configured So, I tried setting the `dotenv` in the `asgi.py` file like so:

```
dotenv.load_dotenv( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.env' ))
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings.dev')

if os.getenv('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`):
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = os.getenv('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE')
```

But this just gives me the same error. Any ideas how to fix this? I checked out this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655488/running-django-channels-with-daphne-on-systemd), but it seems ridiculous/redundant to set the environment variables in `daphne.service`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be the path you have specified for your `ExecStart` line

You have:

```
ExecStart=/home/django/myproject/venv/bin/python ...
```

which should be

```
ExecStart=/home/django/myproject/venv/bin/daphne ...
```

see https://build.vsupalov.com/django-systemd-crashcourse/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll upvote it. However, I resolved the issue by reordering my WSGI config.

Comment: You should have added how you rearranged your configuration. It will help others who had similar issues @nonamorando